# Exclude go packages from auto import in VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to exclude packages from being auto imported similarly to how it works in GoLand

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#exclude-from-auto-import

Is there a setting in the Google Go extension or another extension that can do this?